# what is the meaning or usage of"--reg-with-procmgr"

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I'm using IPMItool utility, when I check the service running status using "ps ax" cmd it shows
ttyS2 Ssl+ 4:24 /usr/local/bin/IPMIMain --daemonize --reg-with-procmgr

I know the usage for "--daemonize"
but I didn't know the meaning or usage "--reg-with-procmgr"
so please explain

I surf the internet but didn't get

Comment: it's possible that the --reg-with-procmgr option instructs IPMItool to register itself with a process manager on the system. This registration could be part of the daemonization process, ensuring that the IPMItool process is properly managed by the process manager.